# One or more fields provided is of type 'Null', a different type is expected

Tags: flow

I'm very new to Flows so I need some assistance setting up a Round Robin for Sharepoint Files.

When someone browses a file in Sharepoint Online they can run a flow which uses a round robin list and counter to send the approval request to the next person in the list.

It seems to be getting stuck with the error - One or more fields provided is of type 'Null', a different type is expected.

I've done some Googling but cannot find a fix.

[image: flow][image: flow2]

Comment: What is the expression you used? Can you add it to your question?

Answer (score 2):

As long as One of the required values is null, the formula won't work and will return this error.

> One or more fields provided is of type 'Null', a different type is expected.

So, you have first to ensure that all variables assigned in "`Set Variables`"  are not null to can proceed and avoid this error